# Click on an Element in list Selenium Java

Tags: selenium

How can I click on the the element "one" in the following code:

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0);" id="Tiles">cat1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="Wid" href="javascript:void(0);">one</a></li>
    <li><a id="Sett" href="javascript:void(0);">two</a></li>
    <li><a id="Th" href="javascript:void(0);">three</a></li></ul></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0);" id="Groups">Cat2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a id="Events" href="javascript:void(0);">four</a></li>
<li><a id="Folder" href="javascript:void(0);">five</a></li>
<li><a id="Cat" href="javascript:void(0);">six</a></li>
<li class="disabled"><a id="Procedure" href="javascript:void(0);">Procedure</a></li></ul></li></div>
```

Thanks:)

Comment: there is no `"one"` element, but only `<a>` element marked with text "one". Also your `html` code is hard readable as it has no indentations

Comment: I'm Sorry for this; I fixed that... I want to click on the button labeled "one" with the ids that I have since I cannot change the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

"one" is not an element, so you can only locate its parent `<a>` element:

```
By.Id("Widgets")
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, "one" is one value from a dropdown list, correct? If  so, you can use one of the following methods to find the dropdown list and the particular value, after you name them in a class:

```
public void selectFromDropDownListFoundById(String detailIDIdentifier, String text, String value) {
        Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(detailIDIdentifier)));
        // Choose to Select by Text or by Value of the drop-down list
        if (text == null && value != null) {
            droplist.selectByValue(value);
        } else if (text != null && value == null) {
            droplist.selectByVisibleText(text);
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("Cannot be both parameters null. Give text or value");
        }
}

public void selectFromDropDownListFoundByName(String detailIdIdentifier, String text, String value) {
        Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name(detailIdIdentifier)));
        // Choose to Select by Text or by Value of the drop-down list
        if (text == null && value != null) {
            droplist.selectByValue(value);
        } else if (text != null && value == null) {
            droplist.selectByVisibleText(text);
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("Cannot be both parameters null. Give text or value");
        }
    }
```